# Given bags A and B, remove all tuples in A that are contained in B

Tags: apache-pig

In pig, I have two bags. Bag A is of size ~200 GB and bag B is of size ~600 GB. They have the same schema. How can I remove all tuples from bag A that are contained in bag B? I looked at Pig's DIFF udf, but it doesn't seem practical to fit both bags simultaneously in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution:

```
C = COGROUP A BY *, B BY *;
C_FILT = FILTER C BY NOT IsEmpty(A) AND IsEmpty(B);
OUT = FOREACH C_FILT GENERATE FLATTEN(A);
```